# Converting subquery to joins for performance

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have taken over a big project, and as the database is becoming large, some of the code stopped working,

Here is the query to find those `rendering_requests` who's last `rending_log` is `pending`, sometimes there are log entries which have no status change and recorded as `noaction` we dont need to count them. That is what I understood from the query.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(rr.rendering_id) AS recordCount
FROM
    rendering_request rr, rendering_log rl
WHERE
    rl.rendering_id = rr.rendering_id 
AND rl.status = 'pending'   AND
    rl.log_id = (
            SELECT rl1.log_id
            FROM rendering_log rl1
            WHERE 
            rl.rendering_id = rl1.rendering_id  AND 
            rl1.status = 'pending' 
            AND rl1.log_id = (
                SELECT rl2.log_id
                FROM rendering_log rl2
                WHERE rl1.rendering_id = rl2.rendering_id AND rl2.status!='noaction'
                ORDER BY rl2.log_id DESC LIMIT 1
                    )
            ORDER BY rl1.log_id DESC
            LIMIT 1
            )
```

for example

`rendering_id=1` is having multiple logs

```
status=noaction
status=noaction
status=pending
```

and

`rendering_id=2` is having multiple logs

```
status=noaction
status=assigned
status=noaction
status=pending
```

when we run this query it should display `count=1` as only the `rendering_id=1` is our desired record.

Right now this query has stopped working, and it hangs the mysql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure I have got this right, but something like this. Think you still need to use a couple of subselects but (depending on the version of MySQL) doing it this way with JOINs should be a lot faster

```
SELECT COUNT(rr.rendering_id) AS recordCount
FROM rendering_request rr
INNER JOIN rendering_log rl
ON rl.rendering_id = rr.rendering_id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT rendering_id, MAX(log_id) FROM rendering_log  WHERE status = 'pending' GROUP BY rendering_id) rl1
ON rl1.rendering_id = rl.rendering_id 
AND rl1.log_id = rl.log_id
INNER JOIN (SELECT rendering_id, MAX(log_id) FROM rendering_log  WHERE status!='noaction' GROUP BY rendering_id) rl2
ON rl2.rendering_id = rl1.rendering_id 
AND rl2.log_id = rl1.log_id
WHERE rl.status = 'pending'
```

Comment: hmm, thanks for the tip, i am trying to run that. right now it is giving me `[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'rl1.log_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: :) okay i did it, I have updated the subquery part `...MAX(log_id) as log_id...` and it returned me 2236 results taking 1 second. I am still not sure this count is correct.